# how to sort the rdd with mixed ascending and descending on multiple fields in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, rdd

So here is the [data](https://github.com/mdivk/175Scala/blob/master/data/part-m-00000).
Structure explained:

> CREATE TABLE `products` (   `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL
>   AUTO_INCREMENT,   `product_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
>   `product_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,   `product_description`
>   varchar(255) NOT NULL,   `product_price` float NOT NULL,
>   `product_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`) )
>   ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1346 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |

**Updated: my environment is Spark 1.6.2 and Scala 2.10.5**

I want to get an RDD sorted by `product_name` asc, `product_price` desc.

I know how to sort the RDD as both asc:

```
val p = sc.textFile("products")
val fp = p.filter(r=>r.split(",")(4) !="")
val mfp = fp.map(r=>(r.split(",")(4).toFloat, r)).sortByKey(false).map(r=> (r._2.split(",")(4), r._2.split(",")(2))
```

Now I have the two fields only: `product_price` and `product_name`.

I can do the sorting:

```
mfp.sortBy(r=>(r._1, r._2))
```

Which gives me the result of sorted by name, and then by price, both in asc;

```
(10,159.99)
(10,159.99)
(10,169.99)
(10,1799.99)
(10,189.0)
(10,199.98)
(10,199.99)
(10,199.99)
(10,1999.99)
(10,269.99)
```

What I need is `(product_category_id, product_name, product_price)`, sorted by `product_category_id` in **asc**, and then `product_price` **desc**.

And I only want the top 3 products per `product_category_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an easier (to me) solution with SparkSQL, here are the full script:

```
val productsRDD = sc.textFile("products").filter(x=>x.split(",")(4)!="")
val productsRDDmap = productsRDD.map(a => (a.split(",")(0).toInt, a.split(",")(1).toInt, a.split(",")(2), a.split(",")(4).toFloat))
val productsRDDmapDF = productsRDDmap.toDF("product_id","product_category_id", "product_name", "product_price")
productsRDDmapDF.registerTempTable("products")
val query = """
select  product_id , product_category_id, product_price,  row_number() over(partition by product_category_id  order by product_price  desc) as p_order from products  """
val result = sqlContext.sql(query)
result.where("p_order<=3").show(200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. RDD `sortBy` always sort in ascending order. Even though, your field is a number, so you can get a reverse ordering just by multiplying it by -1. I used a case class to make your code a bit more readable.

```
case class Info(product_category_id: Int, product_name: String, product_price: Double)

val rdd = sc.textFile("products").map(line => line.split(",")).filter(!_.isEmpty)

val infos = rdd.map { split =>
    Info(
        product_category_id = split(1),
        product_name = split(2),
        product_price = split(4)
    )
}

val sorted = infos.sortBy(info => (info.product_category_id, -info.product_price))
```

Bad news is, this way you're not grouping by `product_category_id`, so you can't get the top 3 products per category. Luckily, Spark `mlib` provides a method to do exactly what you want, implemented using a bounded priority queue.

```
import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.MLPairRDDFunctions._
val keyByCategory = infos.keyBy(_.product_category_id)
val topByKey: RDD[(Int, Array[Info])] = keyByCategory.topByKey(3)(Ordering.by(-_.product_price))
val topWithKeysSorted = topByKey.sortBy(_._1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Miguel, filterNot is not recognized here

Comment: I didn't remember it's not present in the RDD API. You can use a normal filter then.

Comment: Yes I already did that, however topByKey throws error here:  value topByKey is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD. I updated the original question to indicate I am doing this in Spark 1.6.2 and Scala 2.10.5

Comment: You need to import the mllib class, and probably to add the dependency

Comment: I did import the org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD and yet received that error.

Comment: It's not `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD`, it is `org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.MLPairRDDFunctions`. The class adds a implicit conversions for key-value RDDs (`RDD[(A, B)] `)

Comment: Thank you Miguel, but I have followed your suggestion. Kindly check out here: https://github.com/mdivk/175Scala/blob/master/video%20code/topByKey_question.scala

Comment: My bad, you have to import all the members of `MLPairRDDFunctions`: `import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.MLPairRDDFunctions._`. Also, keep in mind that if you call `topByKey` without the second group of parameters, the compiler will try to find an `Ordering` for your type. If you're working with tuples, that means it will sort all the tuple fields in ascending order. You'll need the ordering to sort by price in descending order.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out, what I get now is: (1,[Lscala.Tuple4;@1788be37), first: (Int, Array[(Int, Int, String, Float)]) = (1,Array((1,2,Quest Q64 10 FT. x 10 FT. Slant Leg Instant U,59.98))), can you help to get all the info extracted in the final result so as to be inspected? Thank you.

Comment: `topByKey` is returning you a `RDD[(Int, Array[(Int, Int, String, Float)])]`. This is, a Tuple2 containing the product category id and an array of the top 3 products by price. You can flatMap it to get the structure you want. `val flat = topByKey.flatMap { case (category, top3) => top3.map(top => (category, top._1,...)) }`. Finally, you can write it back to disk `flat.saveAsTextFile("...")`. Keep in mind that this will write multiple files. If the number of categories is not too big, you can also get the data into the driver with `flat.collect()` and check them out.

Comment: Thank you Miguel, there might be something missing in the whole procedure, the result is not correct.  I have updated my finding and posted in here: https://github.com/mdivk/175Scala/blob/master/video%20code/topByKey_question.scala

Comment: The result variable is wrong. Your pattern matching with `Array` is only extracting the first element of the array. Keep in mind that a `map` gets a row of the RDD and returns another row (always). To unroll the array we need a flatMap (which return 0 or more rows from the given one). `topWithKeysSorted.flatmap { case (k, top3) => top3.map { case (v1, v2, v3, v4) => (k, v1, v2, v3, v4) } }`. The flatMap function is returning the 3 rows per category, which come from the `top3.map(...)`.

Comment: By the way, `topByKey` gives you the top N elements, but they're not guaranteed to be sorted, so you can sort them in this `flatMap`.

Comment: I trust your suggestion will for sure lead to a solution I want, but it is really a bit confuse here with the pure RDD solution, thank you anyway.